# Disabling preemption for one node

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, preemption

My question is pretty straightforward: since you can [force a job to run on a specific node](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/), is it possible to disable preemption on a given node ?

Like, if I force a pod to execute on that node I know for sure that it won't get preempted ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`...is it possible to disable preemption on a given node`

No, pod preemption doesn't apply at worker node level. Instead, define a [priority class](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/pod-priority-preemption/#user-exposed-information) with `preemptionPolicy: Never`, then use this class in your pod spec `priorityClassName: <the top priority class that you defined>`.